# What is the Azure Container Registry IP range to whitelist?

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I have an Azure App Service which uses an Azure container registry (SKU: Basic).
I would like to put in networking restrictions under SCM portion.
[image]

Where can I find the Azure Container Registry IP range to whitelist?

Comment: Could this reply  help you?

Answer (score 1):

If your organization has policies to allow access only to specific IP addresses or address ranges, download [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519)

To find the ACR REST Endpoint IP ranges, search for “AzureContainerRegistry“ in the JSON file. Also, you can filter for Specific Regions.

Note

> IP address ranges for Azure services can change, and updates are
> published weekly. Download the JSON file regularly, and make necessary
> updates in your access rules. If your scenario involves configuring
> network security group rules in an Azure virtual network or you use
> Azure Firewall, use the `AzureContainerRegistry` service tag instead.

For more details, you could refer to [configure rules to access an Azure container registry behind a firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-firewall-access-rules).

Comment: Good reply, but below sentence is confusing, because talks about a different scenario (how to reach ACR from another services):



For more details, you could refer to configure rules to access an Azure container registry behind a firewall.